# python skip useless data and read specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x

my text file has 20 pages long and i need to print specific data

my text file looks like:

```
123mcx    version 1.5.0 ld=fri Apr 09 08:00:00 MST 2008                12/10/12 11:59:03
 ***************************************************************************************  
1-       c ==== CELLS ====                                                               
    2-       1 0   1                   $ outside                                             
    3-       2 102 -0.001 -1 23 51                                                           
    4-       c                                                                               
    5-       21 3   -4.15e-4 -21                          $ detector                         
    6-       22 5   -11.34   -22 21                 $ Pb                                     
    7-       23 6   -7.87    -23 22                 $ Fe tube                                
    8-       c                                                                               
    9-       50 7000 -1.7  -51 41                         
multiplier bins
 att  constant    material   reactions or material-rho*x pairs
     1.02400E+00      3        103
  time  bins

     -i            to  5.00000E+02 shakes
      5.00000E+02  to  1.06000E+03 shakes
      1.06000E+03  to  1.69000E+03 shakes
      1.69000E+03  to  2.40000E+03 shakes
      2.40000E+03  to  3.19000E+03 shakes
      3.19000E+03  to  4.08000E+03 shakes
      4.08000E+03  to  5.08000E+03 shakes
      5.08000E+03  to  6.19000E+03 shakes
      6.19000E+03  to  7.43000E+03 shakes
      7.43000E+03  to  8.84000E+03 shakes

multiplier bin:   1.02400E+00    3        103                                                                         
        time

    5.0000E+02   5.54627E-06 0.0004-------- [I only need this data start here]
    1.0600E+03   2.40573E-06 0.0018
    1.6900E+03   2.11609E-06 0.0026
    2.4000E+03   2.04138E-06 0.0033
    3.1900E+03   2.01640E-06 0.0038
    4.0800E+03   2.07022E-06 0.0043
    5.0800E+03   2.11266E-06 0.0047
    6.1900E+03   2.16806E-06 0.0050
    7.4300E+03   2.24147E-06 0.0053
    8.8400E+03   2.32872E-06 0.0056
    1.0400E+04   2.36765E-06 0.0060
    1.2200E+04   2.50930E-06 0.0061
    1.4100E+04   2.43235E-06 0.0065
    1.6400E+04   2.69267E-06 0.0066-----[end]
1analysis of the results in the tally fluctuation chart bin 
(tfc) for tally  14 with nps =1598425200    print table 160
normed average 7.174350E-05          unnormed history  = 8.85335E-01
 estimated error    = 0.0014          estimated variance of the variance  = 0.0000
```

i need to skip all data and print only i need
like:

```
5.0000E+02   5.54627E-06 0.0004
1.0600E+03   2.40573E-06 0.0018
1.6900E+03   2.11609E-06 0.0026
2.4000E+03   2.04138E-06 0.0033
3.1900E+03   2.01640E-06 0.0038
4.0800E+03   2.07022E-06 0.0043
5.0800E+03   2.11266E-06 0.0047
6.1900E+03   2.16806E-06 0.0050
7.4300E+03   2.24147E-06 0.0053
8.8400E+03   2.32872E-06 0.0056
1.0400E+04   2.36765E-06 0.0060
1.2200E+04   2.50930E-06 0.0061
1.4100E+04   2.43235E-06 0.0065
1.6400E+04   2.69267E-06 0.0066
```

after that i need to add only second column numbers like

```
(5.54627E-06 +  2.40573E-06 + 2.11609E-06 + ...+ 2.69267E-06) = 3.504897E-05
```

please help me to know how to skip the data and print only i want

thank you

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  How close did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression on each line:

5.0000E+02   5.54627E-06 0.0004 would look something like:

```
import re 
goodLineRegex = r'\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+\s{3}\d+\.\d+E[+-]\d+\s\d+\.\d+'

for line in file:
     m = goodLineRegex.match(line)
     if m is not None:
         do_something(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to find the text that matches your search criteria

Answer (score 0):

```
data = numpy.genfromtxt('filename', skip_header=?, skip_footer=?, usecols=[1])
print data.sum()
```

skip_header : int, optional
    The numbers of lines to skip at the beginning of the file.

skip_footer : int, optional
    The numbers of lines to skip at the end of the file

usecols : sequence, optional
    Which columns to read, with 0 being the first.  For example,
    `usecols = (1, 4, 5)` will extract the 2nd, 5th and 6th columns.

You could also combine this with the regex based approaches, since genfromtxt will take a generator in place of a file.

Comment: python error pop up which is unexpected keyword argument 'skipheader'

Comment: should i download some program? or should i put def about skipheader?

Comment: it looks like I had a typo in my code, below I pasted from the documentation, it should be skip_header with a underscore